# how to split a string using regex(.match())?

Tags: javascript, regex

how to make a RegEx to split the string like

presently i am using this input=input.match(/\w+|"[^"]*"+|(([^)]+))+/g);

input1: ("java") AND ("operating systems" AND "c" AND c++)

but output is:"java",AND,("operating systems" AND "c" AND c++)

it should come like : ("java"),AND,("operating systems",AND,"c",c++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To come up with the exact output to the input that you posted, replacing all whitespace with a comma except the whitespace that's inside quotations:

```
var originalString = '"("java") AND ("operating systems" AND "c" AND c++)"';
var newString = originalString.replace(/\s+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/gi, ',');
```

@Christoffer's suggestion would work too with a little adjustment since your use-case only involves three words (it also makes it a little easier to understand what's going on):

```
var originalString = '"("java") AND ("operating systems" AND "c" AND c++)"';
var newString = originalString.replace(/\s+(AND|OR|NOT)\s+/gi, ',$1,');
```

Comment: Check it out using [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iQ7cR4/1) - to the right there is an explanation section that can do a much better job at explaining it then I can!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do a simple replace?

```
string input1 = ("java") AND ("operating systems" AND "c" AND c++);
input1 = input1 .replace("AND ", ",AND,");
```

Comment: hey @ christoffer thanks for the reply ..but it could be AND |OR| NOT|some string